# How to pass values to an anonymous function, that is referenced with a map literal?

Tags: clojure

I was wondering if anybody knew any concise ways (if possible) to pass values to this anonymous functions 'x' parameter value?

```
(def Holder { :add-values (fn [x] (* x x)) })
```

Also how could I use the same method, to apply values to this anonymous functions 'y' parameter?

```
{:another-function (fn [y] (* y y))}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't ((:add-values Holder) 33) concise enough?

Comment: null pointer exception

Comment: user> (def Holder { :add-values (fn [x] (* x x)) })
#'user/Holder
user> ((:add-values Holder) 33)
1089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user=> (def Holder { :add-values (fn [x] (* x x)) }) 
#'user/Holder
user=> ((:add-values Holder) 3)
9
user=> ((:another-function {:another-function (fn [y] (* y y))}) 3)
9
```